# Microdata vs. Microformats

Tags: google-search, microdata, microformats

Just like the title says: it seems to me that Microdata has a few advantages over Microformats, with the only drawback being a bit more verbose. Is this all the story?

It seems that Google supports both equally; is there anything else which I should consider?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microdata vs RFDa](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2860/microdata-vs-rfda)

Comment: @John Conde - though related, this is not really a duplicate of [Microdata vs RFDa](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/2860/70), as RDFa is a more advanced/formal approach to semantic markup, see [my answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/microdata-vs-microformats/3037#3037) for a bit more on this including links to elaborate explanations.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between Microdata and Microformats?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/72685/17633)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite being (as of today) way too short for a subject like this, the Wikipedia [article about Microdata (HTML5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML5%29) still puts the relationship between the three common semantic markup approaches nicely:

> Microdata can be viewed as an extension of the existing [microformat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microformat) idea which attempts to address the deficiencies of microformats without the complexity of systems such as [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa).

So from a distance (i.e. ignoring technical differences) I'd say this pretty much *is all the story* indeed (for Microdata vs. Microformats - [RDFa is another subject matter](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2860/microdata-vs-rfda)), consequently your main concern should be the target 'audience', i.e. whether your format of choice is supported by the clients you expect to consume your semantically enriched content - if Google is the usual benchmark here, it appears your are free to go with the upcoming HTML5 standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I chose to go with microdata: there's "official support" and I don't have to litter my markup with attributes. (RDFa has an incredible overhead, so I never really considered it)

Answer (score 0):

It is also good to keep in mind that **Microformats are an open standard**. This means anyone can contribute.

To be honest picking which one to use is **totally dependent on your website needs**. If there is a Microformat for what you need I suggest using it instead, at least for now. They are 5 years old and Microdata is still in the works.

Microformats also get to recommendation faster than the W3C does, or at least it feels that way.

Answer (score 0):

One crucial difference between the two is that *microdata* rely upon the `itemprop` model while *microformats* rely (mostly) upon the `class` model.

This is important for markups that use *html sanitization*, such as MediaWiki's *wikitext*, where `class` attributes are accepted but `itemprop` attributes are *sanitized* (i.e. removed). So only *microformats* can be used in MediaWiki.

Example:

In MediaWiki, a *microformats* syntax such as:

```
<div class="fn">John Doe</div>
```

will be accepted and render exactly as is, 
but a *microdata* syntax such as:

```
<div itemprop="name">John Doe</div>
```

will render as:

```
<div>John Doe</div>
```

See also:

- http://microformats.org/wiki/class-design-pattern
- http://microformats.org/wiki/mediawiki-mark-up-issues