# What is the difference between Microdata and Microformats?

Tags: microdata, microformats

I have searched quite a bit for this and I am not happy enough with what I have read.
I also found these questions here:

- [Microdata vs. Microformats](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/microdata-vs-microformats)
- [What are the advantages of Schema.org's Microdata vs. Microformats et al?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48586/what-are-the-advantages-of-schema-orgs-microdata-vs-microformats-et-al)

I have a news/social network site in Spanish and wanted to know what would be the best format to implement.

Currently, I have both running. But I want to know if it is better to have only one, if so, which one would best fit my site? Or, **can I keep both of them?**

I want to target most search engines, not only Google.

Comment: You can take a look into my question: [How many times can I repeat a keyword without looking spammy to Google?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72382/how-many-times-can-i-repeat-a-keyword-without-looking-spammy-to-google) That can help you as it helped me. About microformats and microdata from what I read it's okay to have both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are [solutions for semantically annotating your content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175699/1591669), but in very different ways:

- Microdata extends HTML5 (e.g., by introducing new attributes like `itemprop`), while Microformats only uses existing HTML mechanisms (like `class` and `rel` attributes).
- With Microdata, you can use almost any vocabulary (a popular one is [Schema.org](http://schema.org/)), with Microformats you can only use the Microformats that are listed in [their wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/).

And yes, you can use both, Microdata and Microformats, for the same document/content. You could even use RDFa in addition, too (see also: [Differences between Microdata and RDFa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669)).

Comment: Good so far, I just forgot to ask, are there any advantages for using more than one?

Comment: @Gixty: Consumers (search engines, browser add-ons, etc.) don’t necessarily support all syntaxes/vocabularies, so yes, it [can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17589792/1591669) make sense to use more than one way. But unless you have specific consumers in mind (where you know that one only supports *X* and the other one only *Y*), I wouldn’t bend over backwards: only implement more than one way if it doesn’t cost you much. And if in doubt which one to use, [I’d go with RDFa (Lite)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669).

Comment: Great, perfect! Just marked it. I think I will go with microdata and RDFa.