# Link to the website creator in the head tag

Tags: seo, html, backlinks

Probably this is an obvious thing, but I am not sure about it. I created websites for my clients, and I am allowed to place back-links to my portfolio site. I placed a link in the footer, but I am interested to also place it into the html head. Is there any way to achieve this?

I have seen code lines like this:

```
<link rel="author" href="https://example.com">
```

I am sure that the author relation is not the proper value for that.

Comment: Doesn't matter. There is no SEO value in this no matter how you do it.

Comment: Google doesn't use author yet.... but it may do in the future as they keep indicating SEO value on the author from site to site.

Answer (score 3):

*(Assuming HTML5)*

#### Don’t use `author`

You are right, you shouldn’t use [`author`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-author), as this link type is for the *author of the page* (if used in `head`), which typically refers to the actual content on that page.

#### Valid link types

You [may](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19428907/1591669) only use link types that are

- [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes), or
- [registered](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#other-link-types) in the Microformats wiki on the page http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions.

There doesn’t seem to be an appropriate link type for the web designer/developer/master.

#### Alternatives

- structured: use [RDFa or Microdata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633) with an appropriate vocabulary
- unstructured: use [humans.txt](http://humanstxt.org/)

#### Related

- giving the *name* (not the URL) of the designer/developer in the `head`: [metadata names `designer` and `web_author`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/76895/17633)