# How do you mark a website you developed in order to show it as a proof of your work

Tags: website-promotion

Well, that is, I have developed some websites and what I usually do when someone is going to hire me is to show him/her some of my previous and similar jobs I've done in order to make them feeling comfortable.

Today I was talking with a guy and I did what I mentioned before, then he asked me: "How can I know you really did those website", and actually I couldn't give him a nice answer since all I have is from those websites are: pictures, documents and some Skype conversations. Most of the times it is enough.

What do you do to water proof your job?

EDIT

I researched about this topic and found a guy who write a tag like this:

```
<meta name="generator" content="Developer Name" />
```

Is it a good or a bad idea?

Comment: Good question. I do not know of a web technology for this. I used to just keep a copy of all work before I started and after along with any notes, contracts, payments, and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two unobtrusive ideas:

- Include an HTML comment in the page source.
- [humans.txt](http://humanstxt.org/)

The problem with having a visible link to your site (in the footer) is that it's less professional.

Comment: Thanks a lot, humans.txt sounds like a perfect idea I will do it from now.

Answer (score 11):

Don’t use the metadata name `generator`. HTML5 [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-generator) that the value is for the *software package* ([e.g., the CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341539/1591669)) used to generate the document, not for a person.

Don’t use the metadata name `author` (as [suggested by Moz](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/76804/17633)). HTML5 [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-author) that it’s for the page’s *author*. While it doesn’t define the term "author", it’s safe to assume that the web designer/developer is *not* the author of the document (as in *content*).

**Alternatives?**

- You could use the [metadata name **`designer`**](https://sites.google.com/site/metadesignerspec/):

  > Credits the designer(s) responsible for the visual presentation of a website.

  It’s registered on [MetaExtensions](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions), so you are [allowed use it in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669).

  ```html
  <meta name="designer" content="Designer name">
  ```
- You could use the [metadata name **`web_author`**](http://www.metatags.info/meta_name_webauthor):

  > Credits the developer(s) responsible for the technical design of a website.

  It’s registered on [MetaExtensions](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions), so you are [allowed use it in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669).

  ```html
  <meta name="web_author" content="Developer name">
  ```
- You could add/edit the file [**humans.txt**](http://humanstxt.org/) of the website (as also [suggested by w3d](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/76814/17633)) and include your name and website URL.
- You could include your name/URL on a page of the website (e.g., on the [Impressum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressum) or a similar page that contains information about the site/accessibility/privacy policy/terms of service/authors/etc.).

Of course, no matter which option you use, you should ask your client for permission.

Answer (score 6):

Ask your existing clients if they are willing to provide references or testimonials to prospective new clients. Some will be willing and some will not be. But it's powerful when an existing client not only says that you did their web site, but how pleased they are with it and how easy you were to work with, etc. Of course, this works best if your clients were happy with you and there were no big problems (e.g. they took months to pay you).

Comment: That is a solution but but I was thinking about something that you could do without the help of your clients, what do you think about the way I found (I edited my question), anyway I repeat your solution is a good one.

Comment: @Castiblanco meta generator is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) as _the software package_ which created the page, such as WordPress, MediaWiki or whtever.

Answer (score 1):

How about this tag:

```
<meta name="author" content="Developer Name">
```

In my opinion is better than the generator one, but it can conflict with the author of the data, not the webpage.

Other method I use, is on the footer I add a little logo that links to my personal website. But of course you need permition from your client to do so, but if asked nicely, I am pretty sure they will understand your purpose of adding it.

Comment: As you state that tag should detail the author of the content rather than the developer/designer.