# Using Schema.org logo markup with SVG images

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org, svg, w3c-validation

I've made a logo which is awesome and I've saved it in AI and SVG format. I wish to use the SVG file on the a site as the logo will appear many times all over the site and would be better than saving the logo in PNG format and having unnecessary server-side requests. Now, this works great using:

```
<svg id="my-logo" height="60" width="60" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
  <g transform="scale(0.1)">
    <image x="0" y="0" height="600" width="600" xlink:href="my-logo.svg" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Now the problem arises when using Schema.org `logo` markup. Using:

```
<svg itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" id="my-logo" height="60" width="60" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
  <g transform="scale(0.1)">
    <image itemprop="logo" x="0" y="0" height="600" width="600" xlink:href="my-logo.svg" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

As I expected it fails W3C validation and I am greeted with the following error messages:

> - Attribute itemscope not allowed on element svg at this point.
> - Attribute itemtype not allowed on element svg at this point.
> - Attribute itemprop not allowed on element image at this point.

Now I know that W3C validation isn't an essential thing but I'd prefer to have a solution which does satisfy both Google and W3C.

I'm sure that some W3C guru will be able to point me in the right direction, I'd perfer not to use DATA URI if possible as I know that could be one solution but correct me if I'm wrong or not DATA URI's are not cachable.

Answer (score 8):

Microdata can only be used on [HTML elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#html-elements) as defined by HTML5. According to HTML5, the [`svg` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#svg) is not in the HTML namespace. WHATWG’s HTML spec [explicitly mentions](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#microdata-and-other-namespaces) that Microdata doesn’t work for `svg` (quoted on 2014-01-02):

> Currently, the `itemscope`, `itemprop`, and other microdata attributes are only defined for HTML elements. This means that attributes with the literal names "`itemscope`", "`itemprop`", etc, do not cause microdata processing to occur on elements in other namespaces, such as SVG.

(a) You could add a meaningless `div` element:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <div itemprop="logo">
    <svg>…</svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Microdata parsers would understand that the content of the `div` element with the `logo` property contains the organization’s logo. **But** as the `svg` element is not part of HTML, there are [no rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values) defined for getting the correct value (= the image’s URL) out of it. So it’s very unlikely that Microdata parsers could *do* something with this information (e.g., showing the logo in a different context).
Note that using `itemprop` on a `div` element [results in a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669), which is not what Schema.org expects for the [`logo`](http://schema.org/logo) property.

(b) You could duplicate the information with the "hidden" `link`:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <svg>…</svg>
  <link itemprop="logo" href="logo.svg" />
</div>
```

(c) You could use the `img` element (according to caniuse.com [using SVG files in `img`](http://caniuse.com/svg-img) has more support than [using SVG inline in HTML5](http://caniuse.com/svg-html5)):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <img itemprop="logo" src="logo.svg" alt="ACME Inc." />
</div>
```

(d) *Maybe* you could use RDFa Lite [instead](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633), but I’m not sure if it works for "mixed" namespaces. But for SVG 1.2 Tiny, [RDFa can be used in the `metadata` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-SVGTiny12-20081222/metadata.html#MetadataAttributes).

Comment: great answer. Problem with using img tag is it does not scale that well, or least in my tests resizing using `width: height:` within the img tag had undesirable effects. I'll give it another shot.... will be a pain to have to use png sprites as this will add 100kb vs 2kb.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply refer to Your logo via meta/link tag as suggested in official documentation: http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing

```
<!-- schema.org item wrapper -->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <!-- This is Your original SVG markup -->
  <svg id="my-logo" height="60" width="60" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <g transform="scale(0.1)">
     <image x="0" y="0" height="600" width="600" xlink:href="my-logo.svg" />
   </g>
  </svg>
  <!-- schema.org itemprop markup -->
  <link itemprop="logo" content="my-logo.svg" />
</div>
```

**Edit**: Changed from `<meta>` to `<link />` as suggested by unor.

Comment: You [must use `link`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) instead of `meta` if the value is a URI (which is what I suggested in [part (b) of my answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/56670/17633)).

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be to save your image as a `.svg` file.  You can use any text editor to create this file and paste in your SVG markup.  Then put the markup on just like you would do for a `.png` or `.jpg`:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/">Home</a>
  <img itemprop="logo" src="http://www.example.com/logo.svg" />
</div>
```