# Does Google parse SVG images as value of the Schema.org 'image' property in JSON-LD?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, json-ld, svg

Structured data markup is a standard way to annotate your content so Google can understand it. However, I am not sure, if Google will **accept and parse** `svg+xml` images as a value for the [Schema.org `image` property](https://schema.org/image).

The [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) shows no errors:

> [image: Google’s Testing Tool shows "All good" for "WebApplication" and "SoftwareApplication".]

Snippet:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
  "name": "Our application name",
  "image": "https://my.company/files/images/desktop-icon.svg",
  ...
}
```

There is a [related question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/using-schema-logo-markup-with-svg-images), but it does not apply the *new* `application/ld+json` format.

Comment: What makes you doubting it?

Comment: I can not find any offical statement or post by an Google employee

Comment: SVG is an image format, it should work fine. But what does the GWT report say under "appearance > structured data"? I have found that sometimes it does not accept things the test tool says are OK.

Answer (score 4):

I guess there is no reason to assume that Google *wouldn’t* handle SVGs as value of the `image` property:

1. Schema.org’s [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) expects an image URL (or an [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject)).
2. SVG is an image format (`image/svg+xml`).
3. Google [does index](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html) SVG images.

(Of course, we can never be *sure*; and things might change always.)

Generally, the syntax shouldn’t matter, as long as it is one of the syntaxes Google supports (currently: Microdata, JSON-LD, and RDFa), and your case is not one of the rare ones where only specific syntaxes are supported.
It would not make sense if Google would, say, support SVG within RDFa but not within JSON-LD.

That said, in the documentation of some (but not all) Rich Snippets, Google [recommends](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82033/17633) the use of ".jpg, .png, or. gif formats". But that that really seems to be a recommendation, not a requirement.

Comment: Google's documentation has been updated to say "The image must be in .jpg, .png, or. gif format." [source](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo)

Comment: This has changed (again): Following the link @thirdender you can find "The image file format must be supported by Google Images" with a link to https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/google-images#supported-image-formats