# Correct image dimensions when using Schema.org's logo/image

Tags: seo, html, images, microdata, google-rich-snippets-tool

What are the correct image dimensions when using Schema.org’s [`logo`](http://schema.org/logo)/[`image`](http://schema.org/image) (e.g., for a [`Brand`](http://schema.org/Brand))?

I want to create a logo for the brand with correct dimensions so that it doesn't look too distorted when showing up in the search results. I can't find the correct image dimensions on the website.

Answer (score 20):

**Schema.org** neither requires nor recommends specific image dimensions. For an `ImageObject`, you may specify the image’s height and width with the [`height`](http://schema.org/height) and [`width`](http://schema.org/width) properties.

**Consumers** of the data would have their own rules, if any at all.

#### In case of Google Search

**tl;dr**:

- For some Rich Snippets that use the `image` property, no dimensions are specified.
- For other Rich Snippets that use the `image` property, Google specifies

  > at least **160x90** pixels and at most **1920x1080** pixels

---

For Google Search, the documentation for their Rich Snippets is at https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/.

Here’s what they define for their current Rich Snippets that make use of images:

- [Products](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products) → `image`

  > The URL of a product photo. Pictures clearly showing the product, e.g. against a white background, are preferred.
- [Recipes](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/recipes) → `image`

  > Image of the dish being prepared.
- [Videos](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/videos) → `thumbnailUrl`

  > A URL pointing to the video thumbnail image file. Images must be at least 160x90 pixels and at most 1920x1080 pixels. We recommend images in .jpg, .png, or. gif formats. All image URLs should be [crawlable and indexable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/). Otherwise, we will not be able to display them on the search results page.
- [Articles](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles) → `image`:

  > A URL, or list of URLs pointing to the representative image file(s). Images must be at least 160x90 pixels and at most 1920x1080 pixels. We recommend images in .jpg, .png, or. gif formats. All image URLs should be [crawlable and indexable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/). Otherwise, we will not be able to display them on the search results page.
  > Only marked-up images that directly belong to the article should be listed in this property. If there are multiple applicable images, please list them all with the important images first.

(Google also has non-Rich-Snippet uses for Schema.org markup, e.g., for their [Knowledge Graph](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/overview): [Organization’s Logo](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/logos) and [Corporate Contacts](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/contact-points) use the `logo` property, but they don’t specify any dimensions.)

Comment: There are some more details about the logo: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo

Answer (score 1):

The Height should be at-least 120px

And if the width is below 100px, then the ratio aspect must not be greater than 3.0.

And images which are too small and no properly in square shape are not included in the +Snippet. Also images that do not pass these dimensions will not be included in the +snippet.

Comment: Thank you. Does the same image dimensions apply for the search results in Google?

Comment: No it takes default image dimension for each type of snippets

Comment: Yes but what is the default settings?