# Can you use SVG as Schema.org logo image filetype?

Tags: seo, google-search, images, schema.org, svg

I couldn't find anything regarding what file types are acceptable for things like [google](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/logos)'s schema.org rendering of a logo in search results.

Since I've not yet implemented a site utilizing the schema stuff I'm wondering if a .SVG file can be used to retain resolution? All I've seen people use are .PNG and .JPG

Comment: There's a great answer here:
[http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/using-schema-logo-markup-with-svg-images](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/using-schema-logo-markup-with-svg-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use .svg files for logo schema. Doing that on our corporate website and it works just like jpg or png