# How to transform RDF to Microdata in a WordPress site?

Tags: html, microdata, rdfa

I have a breadcrumb with RDF data and I want to adapt it to Microdata. First of all, I'm not sure about the structure, because it will work on a WordPress template.

But I found this code: http://www.seomix.fr/fil-dariane-chemin-navigation/ (I don't paste the code here to respect the author).

Let's see some attributes, I do have:

1. `span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"`
2. `rel="v:url" property="v:title"`
3. `div class="path" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"`
4. `span id="breadex"`
5. `id="breadh"`

What does they mean and what should I put instead of them? I have that example of Microdata, but I'm not able to make relations:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <a href="http://www.example.com/books" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="title">Books</span>
  </a> ›
  <div itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/books/authors" itemprop="url">
      <span itemprop="title">Authors</span>
    </a> ›
    <div itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
      <a href="http://www.example.com/books/authors/stephenking" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Stephen King</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** At the end I'm gonna keep the RDFa format. My problem was that the HTML5 don't validate RDFa, it returns:

"Attribute xmlns:v not allowed here."

"Attribute with the local name xmlns:v is not serializable as XML 1.0."

Source: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.seozeta.com%2Fblog%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

But I noticed that there are themes of WordPress on Themeforest that also use RDFa without validation, so I think it's ok.

About the subject of that post, I was not sure how to relate RDFa with Microdata. For example, what is 'breadex', a child or a parent? Is the typeof='v:Breadcrumb' the itemscope equivalent? Which one is which one? Now I don't need it to know, but feel free to post a list with the equivalences/relations for others. I think this information will be usefull for sure.

Comment: What is wrong with your Microdata example?

Comment: That I don't know which atribute corresponds to the others. For example, I can understand the itempromp=child (it's obvious), but not to which one corresponds with the RDFa format. Another example: RDFa defines what is an url, and using Microdata it seems that it's not possible.

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand you correctly here. Do you want to know how to convert RDFa to Microdata in general (not only for this specific example)?

Comment: I would like to do it for the example of the link that I posted above. It contains a lot of attributes that I'm not able to relate with the attributes that I need to put of Microdata. (All of this is 'cause RDFa is not HTML5 valid and I need to validate it).

Comment: But your Microdata example already is equivalent. The Microdata counterparts of all the RDFa attributes you mentioned already are in your example. -- And note that it’s totally fine and [valid to use RDFa in HTML5](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633).

Comment: Thanks unor. I updated the post. At the end I will keep the RDFa because I checked other themes that they use it also. But if you take a look at the w3c link that I posted, you will see the 2 errors that it returns. They say that RDFa «can already be used in HTML 4.01, HTML5, XHTML...», but nothing about validation, though. Thanks anyway for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s [valid to use RDFa in HTML5](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633).

While `xmlns` still works, it is [deprecated in HTML+RDFa 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-html-rdfa-20130822/#xmlns--prefixed-attributes). You should use the `prefix` attribute instead. If only one vocabulary is used, you could also use the `vocab` attribute instead of `prefix`.

RDFa is much more powerful than Microdata. [RDFa Lite](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-rdfa-lite-20120607/) (a subset of RDFa), however, is very similar to Microdata.

---

Here is a small example specifying a person and his name with the Schema.org vocabulary.

**Microdata:**

```html
<p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="name">John Doe</span>
</p>
```

**RDFa Lite 1.1:**

```html
<p vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Person">
  <span property="name">John Doe</span>
</p>
```

(See my last example for a smaller variant.)

You could even define the vocabulary on the `body` (or any other parent) element and use it in the whole document:

```html
<body vocab="http://schema.org/">

  <p typeof="Person"> <!-- using http://schema.org/Person -->
    <span property="name">John Doe</span>
  </p>

  <p typeof="LocalBusiness"> <!-- using http://schema.org/LocalBusiness -->
    <span property="name">ACME Inc.</span>
  </p>

</body>
```

By using `prefix`, you could even use several different vocabularies, for example Schema.org and [FOAF](http://www.foaf-project.org/):

```html
<body vocab="http://schema.org/" prefix="foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">

  <p typeof="Person"> <!-- using a class from schema.org -->
    <span property="name">John Doe</span> <!-- using a property from schema.org -->
    <span property="foaf:nick">JD</span> <!-- using a property from FOAF -->
  </p>

</body>
```

---

In fact, because [RDFa predefines some prefixes](http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1), you wouldn’t have to use `vocab`/`prefix` if you use, for example, Schema.org. Just prefix the terms with `schema:` and you are done:

```html
<p typeof="schema:Person">
  <span property="schema:name">John Doe</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Your information is perfect! I used vocab instead of xmlns:v and it passes the validation! Awesome! Thank you a lot! Also for the extended explanation. It's totally useful :)

Comment: Hi @unor. I notticed that Google Webmaster Tools returns these errors: «Missing: author. Missing: entry-title. Missing: update.» in reference to the post pages. I'm ussing the RDFa on the breadcrumbs. Can I use them separately? The author in another place, for example the meta information of the post? («Published by admin, july 2014 in Category»).

Comment: @Gerard: I think you should create a new question for this.

Comment: I created a specific question for this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67253/a-good-way-to-use-rdfa-in-a-wordpress-post