# itemprop for canonical link and meta description in the head

Tags: html5, schema.org, microdata, w3c-validation

I've a problem with validation of the code provided by Google. Idea is (simplified):

```
<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  <title itemprop="name">Example.com - Best Website in the World</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Blah Blah Blah" itemprop="description">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" itemprop="url">
</head>
```

Inspired by [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitename) (see markup example).

The main problem is that the code above isn't valid:

> Attribute `itemprop` not allowed on element `meta` at this point.
>   Attribute `itemprop` not allowed on element `link` at this point.

But if I remove `itemprop`, Google Structure Tool no longer recognizes the `url` and `description` as properties.

Please tell me why is that, I mean why does Google provide non-valid code and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is invalid HTML+Microdata. It is not allowed to have the `itemprop` attribute on `meta`[`name`] or `link`[`rel`] elements.

The solution for **HTML+Microdata** would be to duplicate the elements:

```html
<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  <title itemprop="name">Example.com - Best Website in the World</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Blah Blah Blah">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Blah Blah Blah">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/">
  <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/">
</head>
```

With **HTML+RDFa**, it’s possible to mix:

```html
<head typeof="schema:WebSite">
  <title property="schema:name">Example.com - Best Website in the World</title>
  <meta name="description" property="schema:description" content="Blah Blah Blah">
  <link rel="canonical" property="schema:url" href="https://example.com/">
</head>
```

Comment: This helps, thank you! Advice me please, do you recommend to use Microdata or RDFa?

Comment: @Mike: I prefer RDFa, and I typically recommend RDFa -- but without knowing more about your case, such a recommendation wouldn’t mean much, of course. --  See [my answer to our question *Microdata vs RFDa*](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633) (or the [more detailed version on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669))

Comment: Excuse me, can you point me to the education material, please, where I can read about usage of prefix inside the typeof property? I see it's working, but I've just read RDFa Lite spec at W3C and they say I can use predefined prefixes when I assign second vocabulary via prefixes but they didn't mention that I can omit vocab property and use the prefixes right inside the typeof. So I'm a bit lost and don't know what's is the right way - should I use vocab or prefixes like you did in the example above? Thank you.

Comment: And in your RDFa example the url property doesn't recognized by Google Structure Tool, even though it's valid, yeah. But it works only if I add second link with this property.

Comment: @Mike: There are several ways how terms can be specified in RDFa. I gave [three examples](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/67264/17633) in another answer. In this answer here I made use of the [RDFa Core Initial Context](https://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1) (not necessarily the best practice; if you are comfortable with RDFa and don’t mind the additional markup, I would always explicitly specify the vocabulary with `prefix`).