# Schema.org 'Service' type for individual page

Tags: schema.org, local-seo

I have a page that offers septic vault repair and I serve all states in the USA only. What I want to do is have an organized schema that tells search engines (esp. Google) that this page `http://www.example.com/repair` is about a service that I offer and I want the search engine to know that it is my organization that offers it.

I chose `Organization` since we have multiple branches instead of `LocalBusiness` as this page doesn't represent any of our branch and it represents that all of our branches offers the same service.

Do you think my code below would work?

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Service",
  "serviceType": "Septic Vault Repair",
  "provider": { 
    "@type": "Organization",
    "telephone": "+1-401-555-1212",
    "url": "http://www.example.com/repair",
    "name": "Don Quixote Septic Septic Vault Repair"
  },
  "areaServed": {
    "@type": "Country",
    "name": "USA"
  },
  "description": "We can fix your septic vault for a very low price"
}
</script>
```

I tested it on Google Structured Data and it seems ok but I wonder if i'm missing something or perhaps im doing it wrong even though Google doesn't show any errors. I still want to make sure and I have points that I want to be clear

1. Am I correct to use the current page URL as the `url` (under `Organization`)?
2. Am I correct to use the current page title as the `name` (under `Organization`)?
3. Am I correct to use the current page description as the `Service` `description`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct to use the current page URL as the `url` (under `Organization`)?
>
> Am I correct to use the current page title as the `name` (under `Organization`)?

If I understand your case correctly, this `Organization` is *the* parent organization of everything (i.e., the one that would be listed in business directories etc.).

In that case, it wouldn’t be correct to provide page-specific `url`/`name` values.

Instead, simply provide the organization’s name and its URL (typically the homepage of the organization’s website).

It would only make sense to add the current page’s service to the `name` (and to link to this page as `url`) if this `Organization` is a `subOrganization` (of the main organization), responsible for this kind of service.

> Am I correct to use the current page description as the `Service` `description`?

The `meta`-`description` shouldn’t affect your choice of the Schema.org `description`. If it makes sense to be the same (and if this page is only about that kind of service, it probably does), use the same value for both (["duplicate metadata" is no issue](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/106283/17633)).

Comment: I get it now :) thanks a lot, have been watching youtube videos lol