# How to properly/semantically markup a scientific publication list on a simple XHTML website?

Tags: google, markup, xhtml, semantic-web

How to properly/semantically markup a scientific publication list on a simple XHTML website?
E.g. those Google markup guides only talk about dates, reviews, etc.

Is there something for those typical publication lists?

E.g. is the following correct for XHTML+RDFa and they way one should do it?

```
<div typeof="ScholarlyArticle">
<h1 property="name">That's a funny article title</h1>
<h2 property="author">Name 1, Name 2, Name 3</h2>
<h3><span property="isPartOf" typeof="PublicationIssue"><span property="name">Funnt conference procedings</span></span><span property="datePublished">2014</span></h3>
<a property="sameAs" href="http://example.com/doi">doi</a>
<a property="associatedMedia" href="http://example.com/pdf.pdf">pdf</a>
<p property="description">Abstract--That is a funny abstract.</p>
</div>
```

Should it be `headline` instead of `name`?
Is it otherwise how one should do it for publications on personal websites?

Comment: I suggest that you explore the semantic markup of Google, Bing and Yahoo, schema.org, and specifically this item:
http://schema.org/ScholarlyArticle

For the list you could then use: https://schema.org/ItemList.

I don't think there is a "typical publication lists", but "list of items", which are in turn marked as "publications".

Comment: dm-guy, thanks for your hint, I added my attempt in RDFa to the question and hope the question is now edited as required.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use XHTML? compatibility?

Comment: @bybe: Yes, compatibility: The website is already up and running, and I can't decide on that but rather just change my particular sections...I am sure I can ask them to "add RDFa" but not to change the whole website from XHTML to HTML.

Comment: @new2web In regards to name VS headline thought - "name" seems more accepted/portable, and leaves room for "headline" as a clarifier, if split out. Since its good practice to make page title differ from `<h1>` "headline" title, this could work to your advantage. "Headline" could be a `<h1>` article heading while the "name" serves as page title, last breadcrumb, `<h2>` subheading identifier, or whatever else. Just gotta pick "name" up at one of those locations. Google "rich snippet test" or hit GWT [search appearance > structured data] to test use cases. GWT schema report will lag, be patient.

Comment: @new2web In regards to name VS headline thought - "name" seems more accepted/portable, and leaves room for "headline" as a clarifier, if split out. Since its good practice to make page title differ from `<h1>` "headline" title, this could work to your advantage. "Headline" could be a `<h1>` article heading while the "name" serves as page title, last breadcrumb, `<h2>` subheading identifier, or whatever else. Just gotta pick "name" up at one of those locations. Google "rich snippet test" and hit GWT [search appearance > structured data] to test use cases. GWT schema report will lag, be patient.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This snippet on its own is not doing what you want because you didn’t specify any vocabulary. Here in my answer I’ll use the `schema:` prefix [as specified in the RDFa Core Initial Context](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/60025/17633). (Not needed if you have a `vocab` on a parent element.)

The `author` property takes *one* name. And it expects a [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person) (or [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization)) type as value. And it doesn’t make sense to use a `h2` for the author names, as the following content should be in scope of the article name, not in scope of the author names.

For the same reason, it doesn’t make sense to use `h3` for the `PublicationIssue` and the publication date.

So this snippet could look like:

```html
<div typeof="schema:ScholarlyArticle">
  <h1 property="schema:name">That's a funny article title</h1>

  <div>
    <div property="schema:author" typeof="schema:Person">
      <span property="schema:name">Name 1</span>
    </div>
    <div property="schema:author" typeof="schema:Person">
      <span property="schema:name">Name 2</span>
    </div>
    <div property="schema:author" typeof="schema:Person">
      <span property="schema:name">Name 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div property="schema:isPartOf" typeof="schema:PublicationIssue">
    <span property="schema:name">Funnt conference procedings</span>
  </div>

  <div property="schema:datePublished">2014</div>

  <div><a property="schema:sameAs" href="http://example.com/doi">doi</a></div>
  <div><a property="schema:associatedMedia" href="http://example.com/pdf.pdf">pdf</a></div>

  <p property="schema:description">Abstract--That is a funny abstract.</p>

</div>
```